# Spark Streaming 2.1 with Kafka 010 - org.apache.kafka.common.errors.GroupAuthorizationException

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

I am migrating an existing Spark Streaming application to use Spark 2.1 and Kafka 010

Here's the code that sets the Kafka parms and creates the direct stream:

```
val kafkaParams = Map[String, Object](
      "bootstrap.servers" -> kafkaBrokers,
      //"zookeeper.connect" -> zooKeeper,
      "security.protocol" -> securityProtocol,
      "sasl.kerberos.service.name" -> kafkaService,
      "group.id" -> groupID,
      "auto.offset.reset" -> "latest",
      "enable.auto.commit" -> "false",
      "key.deserializer" -> classOf[StringDeserializer],
      "value.deserializer" -> classOf[StringDeserializer]
    )

val inputDataDstream = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream[String, String](ssc,
      PreferConsistent,
      Subscribe[String, String](kafkaTopics, kafkaParams))
```

I am running into this error when I launch the application:

```
org.apache.kafka.common.errors.GroupAuthorizationException: Not authorized to access group: spark-executor-dced_kafka_grp
```

Also I noticed this when I launch the application:

```
WARN KafkaUtils: overriding executor group.id to spark-executor-dced_kafka_grp
```

Has anyone seen this as well in their applications? Our current Kafka ACLs are set for the group.id(dced_kafka_grp) that I supply to Spark, since spark is appending spark-executor- it probably makes sense that it will fail?

Do I need to update the Kafka ACLs to allow access for **spark-executor-**dced_kafka_grp?
Or is there a configuration or something else I need to change?

Answer (score 0):

I have just ran into the same issue and figured out that you need to add the relevant ACLs.

A look at [the relevant Spark + Kafka Integration code](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/5059255d91fc7a9810e013eba39e12d30291dd08/external/kafka-0-10/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/streaming/kafka010/KafkaUtils.scala#L212) shows that the prefix is hardcoded:

```
val groupId = "spark-executor-" + originalGroupId
logWarning(s"overriding executor ${ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG} to ${groupId}")
kafkaParams.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, groupId)
```

Please note that the API for Kafka brokers 0.10 or higher is still marked as @Experimental so this might change in the future.